# Return shamsi calendar in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I ran this script in SQL Server 2014:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), N'yyyy/MM/dd', N'fa')
```

But the result is a Gregorian date instead of a Persian date.
The collation is `Arabic_CI_AS`.

Comment: I suspect you don't have the language/culture pack installed on the host. I can't replicate your problem: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uTnWm66R)

Comment: `FORMAT` delegates to the .NET Framework, so things like the collation become mostly irrelevant, just whether or not .NET (and by extension the underlying OS) has access to the culture. `fa` is not available on Windows Server 2008, for example (only 2008 R2 onwards), which is a server release that SQL Server 2014 supports.

Comment: It is not related to your code or even collation.  Your code works in my environment. I agree with Larnu's comment.